# Display local html page inside WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have an html file (which consists of both text and images) in my `Documents` library (it need not exactly be over there, what I mean to emphasize is - it's *not* in the internet and *not* included within the app package since it's dynamic content and created after the app has been deployed).

I want to display the contents of this page within a `WebView`. How would I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) copy your HTML Files to the LocalState Directory of your App which sits here: C:\Users\YourUSerName\AppData\Local\Packages\YourApp\LocalState.

You then can Access this with: ms-appdata:///local/

Very Basic example:

```
string url = "ms-appdata:///local/myWebpage.html";
webView.Navigate(new Uri(url));
```

You can find a lot of Information and samples in this sample download: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7

Comment: Thank you - I was unsure about whether the LocalState directory of the App could be accessible by a desktop executable even if it knew the package name (hasn't Windows disabled other apps' access to Apps' directories ?) - going to check this out soon as I reach home.

Comment: Copying is not a problem but the `WebView` can't load webpages located anywhere outside the package itself, including the `LocalState` directory.